# Angular Filter Array by Date duration

Tags: angular

I have a list of array i need to filter the list by Dates. Im getting the date from ngx-daterangepicker-material . I have 2 dates i need to filter data which is between these dates.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Date</label>
        <input type="text" ngxDaterangepickerMd [(ngModel)]="selected" (change)="getClaims()" [locale]="{applyLabel: 'ok', format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'}" class="form-control"/>

    </div>
```

.ts

```
if(this.selected){

    this.from = this.selected.startDate.format("DD-MMM-YYYY");
    this.to = this.selected.endDate.format("DD-MMM-YYYY")
    console.log(this.from); //01-Jul-2019 showing in this format
    console.log(this.to);

    console.log(this.data10.filter((item: any) =>
    item.responded_at >= this.from && item.responded_at <= this.to
    ));
}
```

Is it possible the problem is upper and lower case of Month ? The month showing like this FEB and im taking data in Feb.

[image]

Comment: Convert the date to number (+responded_at) and then it will be easy to check if another date is between those numbers.

Comment: Can you please tell how ill covert and filter it  ?

Comment: Sure - I am adding it in an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use getTime() of the Date object. It returns the number of milliseconds and it makes your life easier when comparing dates. Something like this;

```
console.log(this.data10.filter((item: any) =>
item.responded_at.getTime() >= this.from.getTime() && item.responded_at.getTime() <= this.to.getTime()
));
```

Comment: One of the properties is undefined. Make sure if all responded_at, from and to properties have values.

Comment: All responded_at have a date. And from and to also have the date values.

Comment: Can you post an example data?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript stores dates as number of milliseconds since January 01, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC (Universal Time Coordinated).

So you can always convert it to milliseconds by adding the + sign before the date variable and then it will be easy to compare dates.

```
  date = new Date('24-AUG-2018');

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.date);
    console.log(+this.date)
  }
```

The first line will log - 2018-08-23T21:00:00.000Z

the second line will log - 1535058000000 which is the number of milliseconds since January 01, 1970

I Added a stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzog4u?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks. But how can i convert date of arrays ? I have dates in array. this.data10.created_at this is how array looks and its almost 200 dates And also need to filter data of dates.

Comment: you can convert dates in Array using the map operator.  
datesArray.map((d) => +d);